# htaccess - Show cached file if present in cache directory, if not, show the original file

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've the same requirement as this question has - [htaccess->show file if in cache directory, if not continue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19973482/4827398) but the only difference is, the solution provided to that question is not working in my case.

**The requirement:**

Display the cached file from the cached folder if it exists.

Eg:

domain.com/abc/def/the_file (requested page)

domain.com/cache/abc/def/the_file.html (the cached version)

Here, `the_file` is actually an existing PHP file (`the_file.php`), which is being processed by the rewrite rules when the URL contains `the_file`.

And I guess that the solution is not working due to current set of htaccess rules that I already have in my htaccess file, though, I'm unable to figure out what's causing it to not work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

The htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# RewriteBase equivalent - Production
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]

# RewriteBase equivalent - Development
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/projects/projectname/]

# Block Directory Listing
Options -Indexes

# 404 Page
ErrorDocument 404 /inc/404.php

# Redirecting index.php to base directory
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# Removing trailing slash from URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}$1 [R=301]

# To externally redirect /dir/abc.php to /dir/abc
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]

### Serving Cached Files if Exists
# check if the file exists in cache dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}cache/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /cache/$1.html [L]
```

**Note:** I'm testing this thing on the production version, as the `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` variable value will differ on the XAMPP localhost.

Comment: Your rules to check the cached file should be at top (before other rewriteRules)

Comment: some corrections of the last two: `RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1.html" -f` ↵ `RewriteRule "^(?!cache)(.+?)/?$" "/cache/$1.html" [L]`

Comment: @Deadooshka, can you please explain me what does the last corrected rule mean? Also, I see that you've added enclosed both the rules in quotations. What difference does that makes?

Comment: Added a preventive negative lookahead for rewritten and internally redirected /cache/ paths. Quotations are optional but more readable imo.